# Quelle est la différence entre « s'être » et « être » ?

Tags: verbes, verbes-pronominaux, auxiliaires

Je suis en train d'apprendre le français, mais je ne comprends pas la définition de *s'être*. La traduction de google définit le verbe comme "have". Quel est le sens du verbe?

Si je veux dire "I have finished my work". Pourrais-je dire "Je me suis fini mon travail"?

J'imagine que je peux seulement utiliser le verbe quand il y a une action après "s'être"?

Comment: Je pense que vous pouvez dire « être finir » dans le passé composé mais j'ai vu aussi que c'est strictement « avoir finir ». Pour moi, je dirais « J'ai fini mon travail » mais je suis étudiant aussi.

Comment: Mais dans ça contexte, je suis assez sûr que c'est un verbe réfléchi. Si vous dites « je me suis __ », ça veut dire "I ___ed (to me/myself)". Vous le utilisez dans le passé composé. Regardez ici: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/je-me-suis-vs-je-suis.3054380/

Answer (score 3):

*s'être* n'est pas vraiment une construction qui existe en tant que telle. Ce qui se produit, c'est que les verbe pronominaux se conjuguent toujours avec l'auxiliaire être plutôt qu'avoir (et ce peu importe l'auxiliaire employé dans la conjugaison "normale").

Le résultat est la combinaison du pronom réfléchi et du verbe *être*, mais ce dernier n'est présent qu'en tant qu'élément de la conjugaison d'un autre verbe.

Answer (score 1):

« s'être » est la version réfléchie de « être ».

Beaucoup de verbes sont réfléchis, comme « se laver », « se passer » mais 
ma compréhension est que « s'être » est utilisé quand vous parlez dans le passé composé.  Je vois sur votre profil que vous parlez anglais, donc l'équivalent est "I ___'ed myself" parce que « être » est utilisé d'un verbe auxiliaire dans le passé.

Quelques exemples ([**d'ici**](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/je-me-suis-vs-je-suis.3054380/)):

> **s'acheter**
>   Je me suis acheté un énorme sandwich.
>   *I bought myself a huge sandwich.*
>
> **se regarder**
>   Je me suis regardé(e) dans le miroir.
>   *I looked at myself in the mirror.*

Vous devriez faire attention pour reconnaître qu'il y a certains verbes qui sont réfléchis toujours, mais d'autres qui peut-être tant réfléchi que non. Ils doivent être appris dee par coeur.

Un exemple d'un verbe qui est toujours réfléchi:

> **se brosser** (to brush ones _)
>   Je me brosse les cheveux
>   *I brush my hair*
>
> Je me brosse les dents
>   *I brush my teeth*

Comment: @Toto Merci pour les modifications. Je suis étudiant aussi. :)

Comment: It's useful to tell learners that they should learn which verbs in French are usually reflexive and which are not. Je me suis brosse les dents assez souvent=I brushed my teeth rather  often, no reflexive in English. Sometimes verbs can be reflexive, others have to be......

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for the feedback ! I'm out right now but I'll fix it as soon as I get home.

Comment: No worries, it was just a thought. :)

Comment: @Lambie Bien fondamentalement, je ne connais aucun des verbes qui sont réfléchis toujours, mais j'ai ajouté ce que vous avez dit. For my own learning, do you know what the *always* reflexives are called? I can't yield any answers from Google...

Comment: Let me try and explain this again. If you want to say in French, brush your teeth/hair, for example, that is always reflexive in French (se brosser les x). This is taught in French textbooks/CDs for foreigners. The French already know it. So, a good intermediate French textbook will explain that to the French. Google does not work for everything. Buy yourself a good textbook.

Comment: @Lambie Ahhh, pardon. J'ai pas compris. En fait j'apprends la langue à l'école et nous parlons seulement les notions de base donc même pour moi, les réfléchis sont un peu difficile. Je vais le corriger encore et je suis d'accord, je dois acheter un bon livre.

Comment: C'est une notion de base: se brosser les dents/cheveux. Pose la question à ton prof.

Comment: @Lambie Pardon, je veux dire comme, les **notions de base**. First year students in Australia learn (atleast I have) présent, passé composé, l'imparfait, futur, *extremely* basic questions and responses, not enough to hold conversation. Which is why I'm self-learning now too as I can stay ahead. Mais vraiment, merci beaucoup pour votre aide avec mon réponse. Je vais certainement poser la question.